# Tensorflow v1 Dataset API AttributeError with ndim

Tags: keras, tensorflow, pipelines

I'd like to make pipeline for optimizing Gpu and Cpu.
[Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/combined+cycle+power+plant)

It's about 10000 datapoint and 4 description variables for the regression problem.

```
df = pd.read_csv("dataset")
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(df.iloc[:, :-1].values, df.iloc[:, -1].values)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
batch_size = 64
with tf.Session() as sess:
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_scaled, y_train))
  dataset = dataset.cache()
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(X_train_scaled))
  dataset = dataset.repeat()
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
  dataset = dataset.prefetch(batch_size*10)
  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  print(sess.run(iterator.get_next()[0]),sess.run(iterator.get_next()[1]))
  his = model.fit(dataset, epochs=300, steps_per_epoch=1000, verbose=0)
```

> [[0.54192635 0.36815166 0.37738184 0.13592493]  [0.31898017 0.33687204
> 0.59490225 0.59597855]  [0.2733711  0.26047393 0.42761693 0.99986595]  [0.77025496 0.98919431 0.45632269 0.66447721]  [0.64305949 0.50236967
> 0.53823311 0.56313673]]
> [429.66 460.53 428.49 446.62 456.84]

In the fitting model, the following error

```
AttributeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

I saw some [issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20698) with this problem.

But it didn't work for me.

**Software version:**
Keras:2.2.4
Tensorflow:1.12.0

Comment: Can you upgrade your tensorflow version? Sometimes there is a version mismatch causing errors like this. Wondering if you can try a different version or not.